# An application error occurred on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to access a aspx page from an IIS server. The page contains a registration form. The browser is opening the page, but when I am trying to enter values into the field and want to save it, it displays this error:

```
 Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What is the problem, and how do i fix it?

Comment: Do you get any exception details on this error page?

Comment: no nothing. this much error i am getting

Comment: it is showing Server Error

Comment: Debug the code on server side to know the cause of error?

Comment: it is showing error database is read only.

Comment: Any exception on server will lead to this error, you need to go deeper and need to print exception

Comment: Ask your DBA to take your database out of Read Only mode.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that while saving some error is occuring and you are not getting that exact error.
So you have two options add below code.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or Use try catch in your save function and in the catch block put code to write enitire exception as string in a text file and then in text file you will have exact error.

But I would suggest first option.

Comment: Can you please paste here exact exception.

Comment: Server Error in '/St.JosephSchool' Application.

Failed to update database "C:\SCHOOL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\APP_DATA\SMS.MDF" because the database is read-only.              Line 840:                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 841:                con.Close();

Comment: It seems that you are using sql express, go to the services and check which account it is using (sql express service) and that account should have read write rights for that mdf file. Provide rights and then check.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b8043fd6-b414-484c-8ab7-15b717e014d8/making-sql-server-database-read-write-from-read-only?forum=transactsql

Comment: @AbhishekPradhan If any answer for your question is acceptable then request you to kindly mark it as accepted, thanks.